# Build error: This app was built with the iOS 16.4 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later

Tags: ios, windows, sdk

I receive this message via email when submitting a build to the Apple App Store. I am using a Windows 11-based development environment. Any suggestions on how to update the SDK? I have spent a few hours trying to a get the answer. Too bad Apple doesn't provide instruction in the email.

Comment: You need to build with Xcode 15.  Since you can't actually be building on Windows 11 I presume you are using some sort of cloud CI tool - You will need to refer to their documentation in order to select Xcode 15 in the build environment

Comment: I made a simple addition to my eas.json file and the problem was solved:
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "ios": {
        "image": "macos-ventura-13.6-xcode-15.2"
      }
    }